# Cookie alert has a higher z-index than top-bar menus

Tags: bug, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, cookies

The top bar menu dropdowns do not appear over the cookie notice, which means I'd have to accept/adjust my cookie settings before opening the site switcher/viewing my reputation gains/opening my inbox (though I recognize that, for this example, I'm not logged-in and thus have no need for those latter actions).

Here's a gif that demonstrates this:

[image: Demonstration of the top bar menu items being hidden behind the cookie alert box]

The "welcome to (x community)" pane does not have this issue, here's a [screenshot that showcases this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t7Pb.png). I imagine that's because this pane doesn't persist at the top of the page as you scroll downwards.

Could this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie acceptance panel has been moved to occupy the lower-left part of the page, and correctly places itself overtop of other elements on the left-nav.

[image: Gif showing scrolling while the cookie acceptance panel is open]

This effectively resolves this issue, albeit in a roundabout way. I quite like the change, though, as the notice doesn't impair the view of questions on the main page anymore.